# Remove automatic excerpts only for single posts

Tags: excerpt

I want to be able to remove automatic excerpts (and keep the custom ones) only on single posts since I make use of automatic excerpts in my archives. I am using this code:

```
if ( is_single() && 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
    remove_filter('get_the_excerpt','wp_trim_excerpt'); 
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Without the condition, it strips out automatic excerpts from all places where excerpts exist.

Comment: Test each half of the condition independently to see which conditional is failing.

Comment: did you try `if (is_singular('post') ) { }`?

Comment: @rudtek Yeah, same issue, it displays automatic excerpts on single posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your code **runs too early**, i.e. before WordPress determined what the queried object is, i.e. whether it's for a single post, a category archive, a search results page, etc.

Such issue could happen if you added the code "just like that" to your theme's [functions file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/), so try doing it like so instead where I put the code inside a function which is hooked on [`wp`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/):

```php
add_action( 'wp', function () {
    if ( is_single() && 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
        remove_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt' );
    }
} );
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, it works. Thanks for the observation and solution!